# Filter out chars not in a set

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

I am trying to filter all strings that I pass through my system, so that I only send out valid chars.

The following are allowed.

```
a-z
A-Z
"-" (hypen, 0x24)
" " (space, 0x20)
"’" (single quote, 0x27)
"~" (tilde, 0x7E)
```

Now I can come up with a regex that searches for chars in this set. But What I need is a regex that matches to chars out of this set so I can replace them with nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it. You tagged Perl, so i will give you a perlish solution:

```
my $string = q{That is a ~ v%^&*()ery co$ol ' but not 4 realistic T3st};
print $string . "\n";
$string =~ s{[^-a-zA-Z '~]}{}g;
print $string . "\n";
```

Prints:

```
That is a ~ v%^&*()ery co$ol ' but not 4 realistic T3st
That is a ~ very cool ' but not  realistic Tst
```

To make it clear:

```
$string =~ s{[^-a-zA-Z '~]}{}g;
```

matches for chars who are not `[^..]` inside the `[`,`]` parenthesis and replace them with nothing. The `g` flag at the end of the substitution is for replacing more than 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression for matching the strings mentioned by you is:

```
[a-zA-Z\\-~]|\x27
```

For further information refer http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html